# How can I map over an array, and have a button access the mapped array without being in the map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Project idea: Essentially a stackoverflow clone. I have a "question" (in my case a code error), and you can post potential solutions to that error.

My issue is while mapping over the array of of "solutions", my button is inside the map so it gets duplicated with every solution. How can I move the button outside the map but with it still having access to the mapped information?

This is in React, hooks.

Code:

```
 {props.errors?.map((error, index) => (
        <Card
          key={index}
          title={error.id}
          extra={<a href="#">More</a>}
          style={{ width: 500 }}
        >
          <p>{error.errorMessage}</p>
          <p>{error.errorType}</p>
          {error.solutions.map((solution, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <SyntaxHighlighter
                  language={error.errorType.toLowerCase()}
                  style={rainbow}
                >
                  {solution.solution}
                </SyntaxHighlighter>
                <Button
                  type="primary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateOn();
                    addSolution(solution);
                  }}
                >
                  Add Solution
                </Button>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </Card>
      ))}
```

Comment: you can't have access of a inner scope from an outside scope

Comment: is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: You are mapping some data, this means there's a one-to-one relationship between the data and the mapped JSX. If you rendered only one button it can't access any specific `solution` in a callback. Is there *some* issue you have with normal mapping?

Comment: Normal mapping? I suppose I'm not sure what you mean, or what the right approach is.

Comment: Normal mapping of data to JSX like in your example snippet.

Comment: Right but I still need the button to not be duplicated and be able to add a solution

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Rendering only one button only makes since if it isn't related to the mapped JSX. Is there *some* issue you have with rendering a button for each solution you a callback for? What would the one button do?

Comment: I want one card, of all possible solutions. But the button allows the user to add a new solution. It's like a a "add a comment", I don't want a "add comment" button for every comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231984/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-hj-paul7).